# Recursive function how to manage output

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a project for creating some word list. I have a word and some rules, for example, this char `%` is for digit, while this one `^` for special character, for example `January%%^` should create things like:

```
January00!
January01!
January02!
January03!
January04!
January05!
January06!
```

etc.

For now I'm trying to do it with only digit and create a recursive function, because people can add as many digits and special characters as they want

`January^%%%^%` (for example)

This is the first function I have created:

```
month = "January"
nbDigit = "%%%"

def addNumber(month : list, position: int):
    for i in range(position, len(month)):
        for j in range(0,10):
            month[position] = j
            if(position == len(month)-1):
                print (''.join(str(v) for v in month))
            if position < len(month):
                if month[position+1] == "%":
                    addNumber(month, position+1)
```

The problem is for each `%` that I have there is another output (three `%`, three times as output January000-January999/January000-January999/January000-January999).

When I tried to add the new function special character it's even worse, because I can't manage the output since every word can't end with a special character or digit. (`AddSpecialChar` is also a recursive function).

Comment: When you encounter January%%, what logic limits the output to just Januaryxx where xx = 00 thru 09?  What logic prevents January10, January11... January 99?

Comment: I mean, the script need to create 100 output with two %, and 1000 with three %. from Junary00 to Junary99 (01,02,03etc...10,11,12,etc...,95,96,97,98,99).

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is the following:

```
month = 'January'
nbDigit = "%%"

def addNumbers(root: str, mask: str)-> list:
    # create a list of words using root followed By digits
    rslt = []
    mxNmb = 0
    for i in range(len(mask)):
        mxNmb += 9 * 10**i
    mxNmb += 1     
    for i in range(mxNmb):
        word = f"{root}{((str(i).rjust(len(mask), '0')))}"
        rslt.append(word)
    return rslt
```

this will produce:

```
['January00',
 'January01',
 'January02',
 'January03',
 'January04',
 'January05',
 'January06',
 'January07',
 'January08',
 'January09',
 'January10',
 'January11',
 'January12',
 'January13',
 'January14',
 'January15',
 'January16',
 'January17',
 'January18',
 'January19',
 'January20',
 'January21',
 'January22',
 'January23',
 'January24',
 'January25',
 'January26',
 'January27',
 'January28',
 'January29',
 'January30',
 'January31',
 'January32',
 'January33',
 'January34',
 'January35',
 'January36',
 'January37',
 'January38',
 'January39',
 'January40',
 'January41',
 'January42',
 'January43',
 'January44',
 'January45',
 'January46',
 'January47',
 'January48',
 'January49',
 'January50',
 'January51',
 'January52',
 'January53',
 'January54',
 'January55',
 'January56',
 'January57',
 'January58',
 'January59',
 'January60',
 'January61',
 'January62',
 'January63',
 'January64',
 'January65',
 'January66',
 'January67',
 'January68',
 'January69',
 'January70',
 'January71',
 'January72',
 'January73',
 'January74',
 'January75',
 'January76',
 'January77',
 'January78',
 'January79',
 'January80',
 'January81',
 'January82',
 'January83',
 'January84',
 'January85',
 'January86',
 'January87',
 'January88',
 'January89',
 'January90',
 'January91',
 'January92',
 'January93',
 'January94',
 'January95',
 'January96',
 'January97',
 'January98',
 'January99']
```

Adding another position to the nbDigit variable will produce the numeric sequence from 000 to 999